# Two different drop zones using dropzone.js with same options and events

Tags: dropzone.js

I have a DIV and a FORM on my page that I want to BOTH use the same config and events.  Is there an elegant way to do this or do I need to repeat the same config and events for both?

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured this out.  Just created a function with all the events and on the init function for both of div and form I simply set init: dropzoneInitEvents().